# html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {} not call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html2canvas, bonita

I want to call **html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){});** in `javaScript` function on `button` `click`.

#### Working Code:

```
function action () {
    if (elementScope == "body") {
         alert("generating pdf.........2");
         //alert("canvas........."+canvas)

        alert("document.body......."+document.body)
        //mypdf();
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){
            alert("html2canvas called...!!!");
            var imageFullQuality = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image : imageFullQuality,
                    width : widthCanvas,
                }]
        };
        alert("generating pdf.........4");
        new  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName + ".pdf");
        });
    }
}
```

#### Error Code

**html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){});** not getting call and remaining code will execute properly.

```
this.action = function action() {
    if (elementScope == "body") {
         alert("generating pdf.........2");
         //alert("canvas........."+canvas)

        alert("document.body......."+document.body)
        //mypdf();
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){
            alert("html2canvas called...!!!");
            var imageFullQuality = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image : imageFullQuality,
                    width : widthCanvas,
                }]
            };
            alert("generating pdf.........4");
            new  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName + ".pdf");
        });
    }
}
```

What is problem here didn't get. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign function instead of assigning `function action() {}`

```
this.action => () {
    if (elementScope == "body") {
         alert("generating pdf.........2");
         //alert("canvas........."+canvas)

        alert("document.body......."+document.body)
        //mypdf();
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas){
            alert("html2canvas called...!!!");
            var imageFullQuality = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image : imageFullQuality,
                    width : widthCanvas,
                }]
            };
            alert("generating pdf.........4");
            new  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(fileName + ".pdf");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it's not working. I want call **html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas)**  from action function.